# Fitting Multiple Input Columns in KNN Algorithm is Giving ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: sequence, knn, valueerror, data-fitting

I have 2 input columns, the first column is binary (zero or one) and the second column is a feature vector of size 100. I want to fit these 2 columns in KNN model in order to predict the category column. I already did OneHotEncoding for the category column and I have outputted 15 extra columns (depending on the number of the categories).

When I fit the model it shows the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is a part of my code:

```
X_level1 = np.asarray(dfCopy[['inputColumn1','inputColumn2']])
y_level1 = np.asarray(dfCopy[['OneHotEncodingColumn1','OneHotEncodingColumn2','OneHotEncodingColumn3',...,'OneHotEncodingColumn15']])

X_train1, X_val1, y_train1, y_val1 = train_test_split(X_level1, y_level1, test_size = 0.2, random_state=20)
```

This is a part of my input data:

```
array([[array([ 0.41164917,  0.33110523, -0.7823772 ,  0.12783737,  1.1618725 ,
       -0.7024268 ,  0.84284127,  1.5140213 ,  0.64215165, -1.6586455 ,
        0.46136633, -0.92533016,  0.50660706,  1.0788306 , -0.9702446 ,
        0.6586883 ,  1.7500123 , -0.15637057,  1.4345818 , -1.9476864 ,
        0.6294452 ,  0.12649943, -2.3380706 ,  0.61786395, -0.45559853,
       -0.5325301 ,  1.2698289 , -1.649353  , -0.18185338,  1.4399352 ,
        1.9842219 , -0.11131181,  0.42542225, -1.3662227 ,  0.57311517,
        3.4422836 , -0.9965432 , -0.58612174, -0.5525687 , -2.5889783 ,
       -0.8159157 , -1.8203335 , -0.58147144,  2.3315256 ,  0.42271224,
       -1.3675721 , -0.87182087,  0.6811211 , -1.5281016 ,  1.0560112 ,
        1.7546124 ,  1.3516003 ,  0.05760164,  0.4792729 ,  0.20388177,
        2.0917022 ,  0.26405442, -1.012274  , -0.7311924 , -0.4222189 ,
       -0.15046267,  1.838553  , -0.9228903 , -0.25226635, -2.7405736 ,
        1.0562496 ,  0.08701825,  0.42543337,  0.2115567 ,  1.3348918 ,
       -0.54058945,  1.2874343 ,  0.72596663, -2.399423  ,  1.7278377 ,
        1.3298786 , -0.6601989 ,  0.55112255, -0.60255444,  2.2411568 ,
        0.31967035,  1.7551464 , -0.70625794, -1.2612839 , -0.82214457,
        1.3652881 , -1.1309841 ,  0.3563959 ,  1.92157   ,  0.9091741 ,
       -0.09321591,  0.09579365,  0.87175727,  0.2785632 ,  1.8571266 ,
       -0.93616605, -0.09428027,  0.5034914 ,  0.55093   ,  1.0682331 ],
      dtype=float32),
        1],.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,], dtype=object)
```

and this is part of the output data

```
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert your input from 2 columns into 101 columns (One column for each feature). And make sure the input raws are equal to the output raws. and make sure all raws have the same number of features.

I think the model is trying (during training) to multiply the array with the weight.

Comment: Hello Karim! but the first column is the feature vector, and as far as I know, converting it to 100 separated columns might lose the value of this feature vector, is that right?

Comment: Hi @karim`, since the array I am dealing with is 1D array, and MaxPooling filtering can be implemented on 2D arrays, I figured out 2 techniques. First technique is taking the max or mean value from the feature vector and use it in fitting the KNN model (taking into consideration that I will lose the direction of the feature vector). Second one is multiplying the vector by itself, get the result and fit it into the model. What do you suggest from your side? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use AveragePooling on 1D array, here is an example: https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/
I don't recommend taking the max value from your data and ignoring all others (that totally depends on your data) but I'll suggest the following: downsize the vector into like 10 (will be 10+1 columns based on your example) features by using the MaxPooling1D layer or AveragePooling1D layer then create training and testing data.
Multiplying the vector with itself you will get the square of its magnitude.